# Collins Dictionary error: “a new design”?

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

I am looking up the Collins Dictionary today for the word "design".

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/design

In meaning 4, I see this:

[image: Explanation of Design]

> 4. uncountable noun
>      The **design** of something is the way in which it has been planned and made.
>
> *…a new design of clock.*

Here, *design* it uncountable. But the example uses "a" before "design". Is this an error, or I am missing something?

Comment: I haven't found a clear explanation from Collins on how it labels nouns, but here Oxford's policy: https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/countable-nouns "In the Oxford Dictionary of English and the New Oxford American Dictionary, nouns that are chiefly uncountable are described as ‘mass nouns’. This type of noun entry may also include an example sentence showing a countable use of the type described above."  Many nouns (like design) can be both countable and uncountable.

Comment: *A new design of clock was revealed yesterday at the trade show.*. Definitely not an error.

Comment: @DavidM Then saying "design" is uncountable is wrong, right?

Comment: **5. countable noun** //
***A design*** *is a drawing which someone produces to show how they would like something to be built or made*.

Comment: Yes, although a far superior test for a count noun usage is 'are / can numerals and equivalent (eg a dozen) [be] used with this usage?' (so 'a subtle light flooded the glade' shows a non-count usage of 'light'). Here, while 'The design of something is the way in which it has been planned and made' is a non-count usage, 'a new design of clock / several new designs of clock' is a count usage. // This might be considered as requiring an 'answer', but there are many duplicates-or-are-they?